# How to tell the browser to remove a file from the cache and get the newly deployed file

Tags: javascript, caching, cdn, browser-cache

We have 3 different webapplications running on tomcat. In the near future, there will be a javascript, all of the webapps have to include. The javascript should be served by an internal CDN.

Now if we update this Javascript file, we want to be sure, that the user will be served by the newest files which leads us to the problem. How can we as the provider tell the browser of the customer to remove the old file from the browser cache and receive the new file?

We've thought about a script tag with the src to a servlet, serving the script dynamically, but still the browser won't ask again next time, because the url hasn't change...

And also we don't want to completely disable the browsercache by adding a random number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this code to **meta tag** will help you get the recent version of the files.

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content ="0" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content ="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content ="no-cache" />
```

**Update** : After comment

> We just want to have a possibility to tell the browser, when exactly a
>   new version will be available.

To achieve this you need **CRC [Cyclic Redundancy Check] Concept**.

Have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/422534/JavaScript-and-CSS-caching-using-CRC32). This will help you out.

Comment: This meta tag force the html file to not be cached, not the js file or am I wrong? Also as I said we don't want to disable the cache completely. We just want to have a possibility to tell the browser, when exactly a new version will be available.

Comment: Yeah most of the answers here would suggest you add random number to the filename , which you don't want. So the other turnaround would be this.